# Sharing docker credentials between Window and WSL

Tags: docker, authentication, credentials, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Environment

- Windows version and build Version 2004 (OS Build 19037.1)
- Docker Edge version 2.1.6.1
- Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL 2

#### Current setup and status:

- docker installed on windows
- created aliases for docker, docker-compose, docker-credential-desktop, etc ...

Running commands such as `docker build`, `docker ps`, `docker pull`, `docker images` all work fine. Now I would like push an image and so of course I have to login first.

#### Problem: logging into docker hub.

- I run `docker login` in the WSL terminal
- I put in my username and password
- I get the following error

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop": executable file not found in %PATH
%, out: ``
```

#### What I've tried so far

`docker login` from powershell works fine. So I created a symbolic link between `/mnt/c/Users/<winusername>/.docker` and `/home/<wslusername>/.docker`. The equivalent works fine for `.aws`, but for `.docker` it was not able to share or even acknowledge the credentials, so it asked again for the user and password and threw the same error as above.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me,

```
sudo  ln -s /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe
```

Linking the executable from windows path to linux path or you can add the windows PATH on you linux PATH.

Refer: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6652

Answer (score 2):

## Update Feb 2021

This is all much simpler now. If you are using WSL2 on a recent release of Windows, just install docker on the Windows side and ensure to configurations:

- In General: us the WSL 2 based engine
- In Resource/WSL Integration: enable integration with your default WSL distro

You will have to restart docker. Once it is done, everything works transparently.

## Below here can be ignored

It turns out that the integration between Docker and WSL is better than I thought. Though it could have been better documented. I was going to change tack and try to install docker in the WSL. So I got rid of all the aliases and restarted my session. Lo and behold, when I ran `docker` there was still something running.

This is because the edge version of docker create the appropriate symbolic links and now I login into docker hub without any problem.